# Can I adjust z-index of Wordpress plug-in FlexSlider?

Tags: css, wordpress, flexslider

In Wordpress, I have two elements in a column: a text block and an image gallery. The image gallery is the FlexSlider from WooThemes.

I have the following CSS:

```
.infront {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 10;
}
.behind {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

I set the "behind" class as the extra class name for the FlexSlider and the "infront" class as the extra class name for the text block.

This clearly has some effect on the two elements, but not the effect of putting the text on top of the Flexslider. They just move a bit further apart in the column.

Any suggestions?

Here is the raw page text:

```
[vc_row css=".vc_custom_1418502637840{margin-top: 0px !important;margin-right: 0px !important;margin-bottom: 30px !important;margin-left: 0px !important;padding-top: 400px !important;padding-right: 0px !important;padding-bottom: 150px !important;padding-left: 0px !important;background-color: #000000 !important;background-position: 0 0 !important;background-repeat: no-repeat !important;}" inertia="0.1"][vc_column width="1/1"][vc_column_text css_animation="left-to-right"]
<div class="yataghan" style="color: #fff; text-shadow: 0 0 15px #000, 1px 1px 2px #000; padding-left: 80px;"><span style="font-size: 65.4545440673828px; line-height: 59.6590881347656px;">x</span></div>
[/vc_column_text][vc_tabs interval="0"][vc_tab title="Introduction" tab_id="1413240816-1-19"][vc_row_inner][vc_column_inner width="2/3"][vc_column_text]
<h1 style="text-align: center;">Tagline.</h1>
<div>
<p style="text-align: center;"><a href="http://unbound-games.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/junk.png"><img class="floater" src="http://unbound-games.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/12/junk.png" alt="Junk Glyph" width="200" height="200" />
</a>Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. <span style="font-size: 17.27272605896px; line-height: 25.009090423584px;">Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. </span><span style="font-size: 17.27272605896px; line-height: 25.009090423584px;">Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. </span><span style="font-size: 17.27272605896px; line-height: 25.009090423584px;">Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. Blah blah blah. </span></p>

<table border="0">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
</div>
[/vc_column_text][vc_column_text css=".vc_custom_1418502481592{margin-top: 15px !important;border-top-width: 15px !important;padding-top: 15px !important;}"]More text...[/vc_column_text][/vc_column_inner][vc_column_inner width="1/3"][vc_column_text el_class="infront"]This Text Should
Be Over Image.[/vc_column_text][vc_gallery type="flexslider_fade" interval="3" images="200784,200785" onclick="link_image" custom_links_target="_self" el_class="behind"][/vc_column_inner][/vc_row_inner][/vc_tab][/vc_tabs][/vc_column][vc_column][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][/vc_column][/vc_row][vc_row][vc_column width="1/1"][/vc_column][/vc_row]
```

Comment: Please share a live example so I can examine the issue. there are lots of factors involved here..

Comment: NOjAN: I created a test page, but the admin has the whole site inaccessible while we are under construction. I pasted the raw page text here. Does that help?